# How i can sort POJO using LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I don't want to implement Comparable or Comparator in POJO. And i know how to sort using TreeSet.

This is my Person class. I need to sort based on name. Please help me on this

```
class Person{
       String name;     
}
```

How i can do like this.

```
   Set<Person> s = new LinkedHashSet<Person>(new Comparator<Person>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
                return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
        }
   });
```

Comment: you are doing it right , whats the prob ??

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid LinkedHashSet doesn't have constructor argument as Comparator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A LinkedHashSet keeps insertion order.  To sort you need to use a TreeSet, it has a the correct constructor

```
TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)
```